# How can i convert video time in second and minute

Tags: php, time

Convert video time

```
  $json_array = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/$PID[$FID]/videos?fields=title,length,from,description,created_time,source&limit=10&access_token=");
   $json_data=json_decode($json_array,true);

foreach($json_data['data'] as $links){

 $video_time  = $links['length'];
```

**238.142** this time to convert **3.57**

Comment: it is actually `3.58` ( 3*60 + 58). How do you get 3.57?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm:

`.142` is irrelevant as you only seem to want minutes and seconds

To calculate the seconds, calculate the modulo by 60

```
238 % 60 = 58
```

To calculate the minutes, remove the seconds from your total time and divide by 60

```
(238 - 58) / 60 = 3
```

=> 3 minutes and 58 seconds

Answer (score 0):

For this you can simply use the `gmdate()` function,

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 238.142); //output: 00:03:58
echo gmdate("H.i.s", 238.142); //output: 00.03.58
echo gmdate("i.s", 238.142); //output: 03.58
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function vtime($lenth){

     $seconds  = $lenth;
     $hours    = floor($seconds / 3600);
     $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
     $minutes  = floor($seconds / 60);
     $seconds -= $minutes * 60;

     if($hours == 0){ return "$minutes:$seconds"; }
      elseif($minutes == 0){ return $seconds; }
       else {      return "$hours:$minutes:$seconds"; }


 } 

echo vtime('304');
```